# JS append text at specific position in a file without rewriting text after this position

Tags: javascript, fs

Almost everything is in the title. I've seen lot of questions that already exist about it but answers have always been:

- get the position where you want to append your text
- create your buffer with the text you want to append AND the rest of the file
- do your fs.write

But now imagine you have a really big file and you want to insert your text like at the second or third line multiple times.

Is there a way do it without rewriting the rest of the file?

[EDIT]

This what i've found to insert text at a specific position, but it rewrites the rest of the file:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

// file path
const file_path = "./Test.txt";
/* test file content:
Hello World!
How are you
I'm fine thank you
*/

// Read file
fs.readFile(file_path, function read(err, data) {
    // Check for errors
    if (err) throw err;

    // Define where and what to insert
    let insert_after = "Hello World!\r\nHow ";
    let position = Buffer.from(insert_after).length;
    let new_text = "NEW TEXT";

    // Get rest of the file to write after inserted text
    var file_content = data.toString();
    file_content = file_content.substring(insert_after.length);

    // Create buffer
    var buffered_text = new Buffer(new_text + file_content);

    // Write to file
    var file = fs.openSync(file_path,'r+');
    fs.writeSync(file, buffered_text, 0, buffered_text.length, position);

    // Close it
    fs.close(file, (err) => { if (err) throw err; });
});
```

Comment: Try to share a bit of code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: I added what i'm using right now

Comment: That's how files work. If you want to add/change some content, you"ve to re-create all, either explicitly or using some code which does it implicitly.

Comment: That's a bit sad, I thought you could do something like move cursor to a position, then append at this position, a bit like a text editor

Comment: A file is just ordered bytes stored on a disk, it doesn't exist in a program. If you need to change those bytes on the disk, you've to re-write all of them. Some languages have a "file cursor", but under the hood they're re-writing the entire file too. If you want to actually manipulate existing content on the disk partially, you need a database.

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you for your answers!